# Sudden disconnection from admin (without apparent reason)

Tags: opencart2.x

Since yesterday, I face up to a strange (and annoying) behaviour with an installation of [OpenCart](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/) (v. 2.0.1.1). After having logged to the admin, the session suddenly breaks (between one and five minutes) and the user is then redirected to the login page (losing all he was working on before, such as product addition and so on).

As I never experienced this kind of behaviour before (I use Opencart for a while now), I wonder what can happen: is it a sudden configuration change (I can't find any trace of it and I haven't changed anything), an issue with the hosting (but how to check it?) or a potential bug (but after some research, I haven't found any trace of this kind of issue)...

Thanks for any ideas on this trouble...

Comment: Could you please upload a phpinfo file to your server, and run file. After running please check the session.gc_maxlifetime value.

Comment: @vural : `session.gc_maxlifetime` value is set at 3600. Do you think it's not enough?